# Received Intent at 'onActivityResult' don't contain my extras

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

I've got some trouble with receive extras from a second activity.

in Activit A:

```
...
// start Activity B
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ActivityB.class
startActivityForResult(i, 0);
...

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
   // get the extras from data
   String extra = data.getExtras().getString("EXTRA1");

}
```

In Activity B:

```
...
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("EXTRA1","any useless text");
this.setResult(0, i);
this.finish();
...
```

The problem is that - back in Activity a - no extras are contained in data at 'onActivityResult'.
Was is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You put your immediate result in an `Intent`, so you should call `data.getStringExtra("EXTRA1')` instead of `data.getExtras().getString("EXTRA1")` because it only returns an empty `Bundle`.

Also your `requestCode` should be greater than 0:

> int: If >= 0, this code will be returned in onActivityResult() when the > activity exits

Comment: ok - but the problem is, that 'data' do not contain the extra. How shall i put the extra to the intnent correctly to return the value?

Comment: You can put the String in a new Bundle, then put the bundle to the Intent via putExtras. I think I had a typo in my answer, not sure if that confused you, but I've updated the answer.

Comment: Intent i = new Intent();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("EXTRA1", "iany useless content");
    i.putExtras(b);
    setResult(0, i);
    finish();

==> same result in onActivityResult: data don't contain extras

Comment: Your requestCode should be greater than 0 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)

Comment: ok - now with requestCode 1: still no extras in data at onActivityResult

Comment: Or maybe call set result with Activity.RESULT_OK instead of 0? 0 means operation canceled but it's quite unlikely. Also could you share more of code when you call setResult? It should not be called when your activity is pausing or finishing.

Comment: the following code is used: private void goBackToMain(){
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("EXTRA1", "any useless value");
i.putExtras(b);
setResult(1234, i);
finish();
}

Comment: Oh, have you tried `startActivityForResult(i, 1234)` instead?

Comment: Sure! But now you mesh up `resultCode` and `requestCode`. I've still no idea how to handover extras. Google discribes the way which we discussed...

Comment: OK - I GOT IT!!! My fault was not the code - the fault was the debugging: I use Eclipse as IDE and in the debug view  Intent field named 'mExtras' will be updated after the first read access. So, I have set the breakpoint AFTER the getExtra() action and all works fine